# Vue.js Asynchronous Traversing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, synchronization

1. Open the page, get `sexList` and `clientList` form the server
2. Traverse 2 sets of data, push the `sexText` into the `clientList`

But the code is not working. How can I modify my code?

Code is here:

```
let sexList = [// store data: sexList
  {
    code: 0,
    sexText: 'female',
  },
  {
    code: 1,
    sexText: 'male',
  }
]

let clientList = [// index data: clientList
  {
    name: 'john',
    sexCode: 1,
  },
  {
    name: 'joe',
    sexCode: 0,
  }
]

mounted() {
  this.$store.dispatch('getSexList')// get sexList form the server

  getClientList({data: 'clients'}).then((res) => {
    if(res.data.success) {
      this.clientList = res.data.data// get clientList form the server
    }else {
      this.$message.error(res.data.message)
    }
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  })
},
watch: {
  /*
   watch clientList，traversing cientList and sexList，push the sexText into the clientList
  */
  clientList(val) {
    if(val && val.length > 0) {
      val.map((item) {
        this.$store.getters.sexList.map((sex_item) => {
          if(sex_item.sexCode == item.sexCode) {
            item.sexText = sex_item.sexText
          }
        })
      })
    }
  },
}
```

After edit, it is working

```
setTimeout(() => {  
  getClientList({data: 'clients'}).then((res) => {
    if(res.data.success) {
      this.clientList = res.data.data// get clientList form the server
    }else {
      this.$message.error(res.data.message)
    }
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  })
}, 1000)

let clientList = [// index data: clientList
  {
    name: 'john',
    sexCode: 1,
    sexText: 'male',
  },
  {
    name: 'joe',
    sexCode: 0,
    sexText: 'female',
  }
]
```

Have another way?

Comment: What part of the code is not working?

Comment: @StevenB  the watcher is not working, sexList and clientList is form server, not in the local

Comment: Is the watcher firing and the logic isn't correct or is the watcher not firing at all?

Comment: See the latest changes